# How can I list all user accounts in the terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line

How can I list all local user accounts in Terminal (whether logged in or not?) The commands `users` or `who` does not provide this information. OS X version is 10.6.8.

I have seen this suggested command - `dscacheutil -q group`

But it only lists domain user groups and non-local accounts.

Comment: As a long time AIX user, I sure miss the system management commands they baked into their unix. [lsuser](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/sonasic/sonas1ic/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.sonas.doc%2Fmanpages%2Flsuser.html) would be nice to have for this purpose.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

How about

```
dscacheutil -q user | grep -A 3 -B 2 -e uid:\ 5'[0-9][0-9]'
```

Comment: I like this option. It returns a bunch of accounts beginning with an underscore, though. Any way to filter this out? e.g. _softwareupdate, _mysql

Comment: Pipe the result through grep `dscl . list /Users | grep -v ^_.*`

Comment: Very cool! I'll have to remember this one.

Comment: This is such an easy one to commit to memory, too.

Comment: When I run this on Catalina, even with `sudo`, I only get myself. `dscl . list /Users` lists all users.

Answer (score 59):

Try this one. I used it to find lost hidden account.

```
dscl . list /Users | grep -v '^_'
```

Comment: That's precisely what @Mark said [here](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/29874/how-can-i-list-all-user-accounts-in-the-terminal/81577#comment34302_29877).

Comment: what is the point of hidden accounts?

Comment: To see uid as well, use `dscl . list /Users UniqueID | grep -v '^_'`

Comment: What if the user isn't there?

Answer (score 12):

User accounts since 10.6 are being managed by OpenDirectory. The backend files related to users for OpenDirectory are here:

```
/var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/users
```

Executing `ls` in this directory will enumerate all local users registered on the system. Executing `plutil -p <file>.plist` will allow you to read some properties for specified user account (i.e. current home directory path).

This is rather undocumented so I accept downvotes. However, this method can be used to inspect a system which is not running, and for which the user has only an offline disk image.

Comment: I like it, but it required sudo/root to work, std admin user got a permission error.  `dscl` works for std admin.

Comment: Thank you, I'm struggling to reset a password for a colleague and every guide/instruction online is showing the old method which no longer works... I was even questioning if the user was corrupt or just missing... however, this has shown the user is there. I've been searching for over an hour and this has got me a little closer but nearly every site in Google is showing outdated info.

Comment: All that's in that directory are plist files. Using `ls *` is not necessary, `ls` on its own suffices. Since the directory is not accessible by users other than root , `sudo ls /var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/users/*` will fail because the file globbing is done before the sudo command, while `sudo ls /var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/users` will succeed.

Comment: @ElhemEnohpi You're right, I've removed the `*` from the answer, as it indeed had no point :)

Comment: Even as root, Operation not permitted.

Comment: @Devon, works on my Ventura 13.1 with SIP enabled.

Answer (score 8):

`dscacheutil` returns more than just local users, for example any users I've queried Directory Services for also show.

I have found this more useful:

```
dscl . list /Users | grep -v "^_"
```

Although it also returns the likes of `daemon`, `nobody` and `root`.

Answer (score 4):

JMTCW to recreate a command line friendly `/etc/passwd` equivalent (though not quite in the same order):

```
dscacheutil -q user |
    paste -d " "  - - - - - - - - |
    sed 's/^name: //;s/ [^[:space:]]*: /:/g'
```

Or if you prefer a space separated output (but parsing GECOS field will be a little more complicated:

```
dscacheutil -q user |
    cut -d: -f2 |\
    paste -d " "  - - - - - - - -
```

Answer (score 2):

If no user home directories were moved then `ls /users` will do.
Except it will also list directories like 'Shared'.

Comment: Never do this. There are much more than just `Shared` that can be there.

Answer (score -3):

You can also type:

`who` which tells you who's logged on, and where they're coming from. Useful if you're looking for someone who's actually physically in the same building as you, or in some other particular location.

`w` which tells you who's logged in, and what they're doing. Especially useful: the 'idle' part. This allows you to see whether they're actually sitting there typing away at their keyboards right at the moment.