# Listing only Mobile Accounts in terminal

Tags: macos, command-line, network-user

I have a way to list all the accounts in Mac via terminal using the `dscacheutil` command. Is there any way to get to know if a particular account is a mobile account or not from the terminal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i figured out that there is a way to list down all the local accounts. And this includes the mobile accounts of the network users. This command gives the above info:

```
dscl /Local/Default -list Users
```

Comment: I get `Too few parameters for list operation` after calling this.

Comment: @MateuszSzlosek: What parameters do you need?

Comment: @MateuszSzlosek You're correct - the syntax is missing a path to list. I've edited the post to request a list of users. Not sure that's what the OP needed though since the title says "list only mobile". Other options exist at http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/29874/5472