# Reading user Plist files from /var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/users

Tags: macos, terminal, catalina, bash, user-account

Identifying user accounts in macOS (Catalina) can be achieved using the following command

```
 dscl . -list /Users | grep -vE '_|root|nobody|daemon|Guest'
```

Which gives me the below output.Note: `hiddenswasti` is a hidden account (not visible in the login/welcome screen) while `swastibhushandeb` is a normal account.
[image]

Referring to a post [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/29874/how-can-i-list-all-user-accounts-in-the-terminal) ,it is inferred that the user specific plist files residing in `var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/users` can be read using `defaults read` or `plutil -p` and contains valuable information to ascertain if an account is hidden or otherwise.
[image]

Issue I am facing is to develop a one liner code (using bash )is utilizing the output of the `dscl` command detailed above and use generated output as input to `plutil -p` to read the contents of `hiddenswasti.plist` and `swastibhushandeb.plist`. Would appreciate help.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please copy/paste from Terminal as text (and apply code formatting), screenshots are hard to read.

Comment: Also, if you already know where `hiddenswasti.plist` is stored, why not just run `plutil` on it?

Comment: Hi @nohillside. dscl command output provides the user account names.We can use that information to look in the var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/users directory for the accountname.plist. I can do the above two steps in two commands.But was anxious if we can use xargs to do both the operations in one single liner.Hope it clarifies.I tried something like this: **bold**  `sudo  dscl . -list /Users | grep -vE '_|root|nobody|daemon|Guest'|xargs -0 -n 1 sh -c 'sudo plutil -p /var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/users/"$1.plist"' _`

Comment: Yes, this should work (if you omit the `-0` part)

Comment: removing the "-0" really worked.Thanks

Comment: Please leave this as an answer, comments are ephemeral, thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can try this to loop through the users.

```
USER_PLIST="/var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/users"

for user in $(dscl . -list /Users | grep -vE '_|root|nobody|daemon|Guest'); do 
  sudo defaults read ${USER_PLIST}/${user}.plist
done
```

This sets up a `for` loop with your `dscl` output and feeds those usernames to `defaults`. You can easily substitute `plutil`, if you prefer. You can make this a one-liner by using the semicolon between carriage returns. I left that out to make it easily readable.

HTH.

Comment: Fails in Mojave and probably everywhere:
# defaults read /var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/users/*.plist
…
Domain /var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/users/*.plist does not exist
— Where * is each and every ${user}